# Merge JSON in Mule

Tags: json, mule, dataweave

I have a JSON Array with two elements in it. I would like to combine them to one json. How can I do that in Mule?

Original Payload:

```
[{
    "Response1": {
        "lines": [{
            "lineIdentifier": 9,
            "result1": null
        }]
    }
}, {
    "Response2": {
        "lines": [{
            "lineIdentifier": 10,
            "result2": ".0225"
        }]
    }
}]
```

Expected Payload:

```
{
    "Response1": {
        "lines": [{
            "lineIdentifier": 9,
            "result1": null
        }]
    },
    "Response2": {
        "lines": [{
            "lineIdentifier": 10,
            "result2": ".0225"
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using dataweave, here is the logic to achieve it.

```
 %dw 1.0
%var input=[{
    "Response1": {
        "lines": [{
            "lineIdentifier": 9,
            "result1": null
        }]
    }
}, {
    "Response2": {
        "lines": [{
            "lineIdentifier": 10,
            "result2": ".0225"
        }]
    }
}]
%output application/json
---
{
    "Response1":input[0].Response1,
    "Response2": input[1].Response2
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Senthil c,

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to use `reduce` operator so that you don't have to bother about number of objects. Please try following code

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload reduce ((value, accumulator = {}) -> accumulator ++ value)
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I believe you are on the way to wrong goal.
You provided simple example which mislead to simple answers.

Let me paraphrase your question as it looks for me:

We have array `[a,b,c,...x,y,z]`

We need merge it to one object `{a1:a, b2:b, c3:c,... z26:z }`

You provided only 2 items but that's the idea. If you really want only these particular items then use any of other answers. But if I'm right and you want it in general then even it could be done in many ways consider cons for this solution:

- code will be "harcdoded" for actual keys like a1,b2,x26
- module structure will be "hardwired" to the keys and so to data
- entire solution will be "hardprinted" for one particular data set

So, in general, this is not good solution when it hardly depend on your data.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using dataweave only

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    "Response1" : {
        (payload.Response1.lines map ((item, indexOfItem) -> {
            "lines": item
        })
    )
    },
    "Response2" : {
        (payload.Response2.lines map ((item, indexOfItem) -> {
            "lines": item
        })
    )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var arr2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];

var arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2);
```